# Get Pane.ID from Dynamically Created Accordion Panel When Accordion SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've been at this for days without success. I have an accordion panel that is being created dynamically. One of the items in the accordion panel is the pane. The paneis given the ID of the record in the database that is populating that pane in the accordion. As an example, if I was creating an accordion for each of the 50 states, the paneID would represent the states admission order (i.e. Delaware, Pane.ID = "Pane_1", New Jersey, Pane.ID = "Pane_3", Hawaii, Pane.ID = "Pane_50", etc.)

I need to be able to pull the ID of the pane when the user selects the Accordion. I've added the following script to the page that binds top the selectedIndexChange event of the accordion:

```
        function pageLoad() {

        $find('<%= Accordion1.ClientID %>_AccordionExtender').add_selectedIndexChanged(
    accordion_selectedIndexChanged);
    };

    function accordion_selectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
        var sinx = sender.get_SelectedIndex();
        alert(sinx);
    }
```

This works in that it fires when I select the Accordion pane. I don't know how to get the Pane.ID from this point on in the accordion_selectedIndexChanged function.

Comment: why don't you `console.log(sender);` then inspect that object in the console window and see what methods are available

Answer (score 0):

First I want to thank @zgood. While I didn't find what I was looking for in the methods, it was what I DIDN'T find. I discovered that I couldn't see a Pane ID, BUT I could see a Heading ID. Using the information in the following links I was able to develop a solution:
[Pass Javascript Variables value to C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/708697/Pass-javascript-variables-value-to-Csharp-code-beh)
[Accordion Selected Index Change Content](https://forums.asp.net/t/1315322.aspx?Accordion%20SelectedIndex%20Change%20Content)
[How to Catch Accordion Pane Select Event](https://forums.asp.net/t/1028679.aspx?How%20to%20catch%20AccordionPane%20Select%20Event%20)

Here are the general steps:

- Created a hidden field
- Created a hidden button
- Captured the accordion change
- Passed the selected index into the hidden field and then called the hidden buttons click event
- Looked up the headercontainer ID in the code behind.

Here is the aspx code:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $find('<%= Accordion1.ClientID %>_AccordionExtender').add_selectedIndexChanged(accordion_selectedIndexChanged);
};

function accordion_selectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
    var control_clientId;
    var sinx = sender.get_SelectedIndex();
    if (sinx > -1) {
        var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById('<%=hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>');
        hdnfldVariable.value = sinx;
        document.getElementById('LogEntry').click();                
    }
}

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="LogEntry" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="LogEntry_Click" />
```

And here is the Code Behind:

```
 protected void LogEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (hdnfldVariable.Value != "")
   {
      int i = int.Parse(hdnfldVariable.Value);
      string id = Accordion1.Panes[i].HeaderContainer.ID;
      //Do Something here
   }
}
```